# How to referemce favicon in index.html from /source

Tags: vue.js, path, favicon

Can someone please tell me, if it is possible to use the favicon.ico file that is located in src/assets/img/favicon.ico? I tried to change the href but it won't work for me. The one in the public will be deleted. How could I reference it in my index.html?
Thank you
[image: The favico]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASE_URL returns public folder, you can use cdn or do not delete inside public folder because if you build this code there won't be src folder.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way to keep my favicon in my source folder?

Comment: I didn't try it actually but I was trying to give you an idea that comes to my mind. Is it so crucial to put it in the assets folder?

Comment: I was told to keep all my media in my img folder. I also checked other applications and I found this: href="/static/images/favicon.ico" for the favicon. And the static folder is not in the public either.